# calculation and display issues in mdx

Tags: mdx

```
OUTPUT                              

                                                      Negative Total    Actual Total
Marketing (Expense) Advertising December    Barlens Actual  24010.44    24,010.44
Marketing (Income)  Discounts   December    Barlens Actual  43380.4    -43,380.40
Marketing (Income)  Sale Promot December    Barlens Actual  18.91       18.91
Marketing (Income)  Sale Sponso December    Barlens Actual  9181.32    -9,181.32
Marketing (Expense) TOTAL       December    Barlens Actual  24010.44    24,010.44
Marketing (Income)  TOTAL       December    Barlens Actual  52542.81    -52,542.81

/* Here Marketing (Income) is being converted into + value (ie -43,380.40, -9,181.32 converted to 43380.4,9181.32) but the 18.91 value is + income so i dont want to display it. Again, The two totals Marketing(Expense) and Marketing (income) are displaying separately but i want to display them in a line so the Total should be 24010.44+ 43380.4 + 9181.32=  76572.16 */




WITH 

MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total] AS
CASE 
   WHEN ([Measures].[Total]) < 0 THEN [Measures].[Total]* -1 /* Actullay i want to display those marketing income has - value so condition should be like this WHEN ([Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing],[Measures].[Total]) < 0 */ 
THEN [Measures].[Total]* -1

      ELSE [Measures].[Total]
END

MEMBER 
[Dim Account].[Account Activity].TOTAL AS
        [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]

SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Negative Total],[Measures].[Total]}
     ON COLUMNS
 ,
NON EMPTY 
 (
    {

        {
            [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Expenses]&[Marketing]
            ,
            [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]
        }
        * 
            [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS
        ,
        {
            [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Expenses]&[Marketing]
            ,
            [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]
        }
        * 
            [Dim Account].[Account Activity].TOTAL
    }
,[Dim Fiscal Year].[HierarchyFiscal].[E Month].&[2016]&[December]
    , [Dim Branch].[Trading As].&[BAR]&[Barlens Event Hire]
    , NONEMPTY([Dim Scenario].[Scenario Name].&[Actual]) 

 )
 ON ROWS
FROM [CubeProfitLoss]
```

I have a problem with data displaying and calculation matter. The following MDX displays all the positive total (MEASURES.Total) and if any negative total then converted them into + value and are displayed accordingly. However, my requirement is  in Hierarchy Marketing i have Expense and Income, i want to display all expenses and those income have negative value and exclude positive income from calculation. So the TOTAL value will be all expenses+ (-) income per Traders. But currently it is being calculated as separately i mean, for example trader (barlens) shows 2 total 1 for expense and another for income of marketing.
could you please find that solution ? I would be really appreciate your help, because last 2 weeks i have been trying to sort out this problem.

Comment: Hi SouravA, whytheq, can you have a look please.

Comment: Is there anyone to help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HAVING` clause

I am a little surprised that your code runs - it is a little strange seeing `currentmember` used the way you have used it - does it serve a purpose or does the following give you the same results:

Maybe the additional `NONEMPTY` is also redundant in the way you have used it? You could maybe simplify all of the ON ROWS section to the following:

```
WITH 
 MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total] AS
   CASE 
      WHEN (SUM([Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing],[Measures].[Total])) < 0 THEN [Measures].[Total]* -1
      WHEN (SUM([Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing],[Measures].[Total]))> 0 THEN 0
      ELSE [Measures].[Total]
   END
   ,SOLVE_ORDER = 2
 MEMBER [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].[All].[Total Marketing Expense] AS
    AGGREGATE(
        {
          [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Expenses]&[Marketing]   
         ,[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]
        }
     )    
    ,SOLVE_ORDER = 1   
 MEMBER [Dim Account].[Account Activity].TOTAL AS
  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Negative Total],[Measures].[Total]} ON 0,
  NON EMPTY 
    {
       [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Expenses]&[Marketing]   
      ,[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]
      ,[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].[All].[Total Marketing Expense]
    }
    *[Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS
    *[Dim Fiscal Year].[HierarchyFiscal].[E Month].&[2016]&[December]
    *[Dim Branch].[Trading As].&[BAR]&[Barlens Event Hire]
    *[Dim Scenario].[Scenario Name].&[Actual]

 //HAVING [Measures].[Negative Total] <> [Measures].[Total]

 ON 1
FROM [CubeProfitLoss];
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but still not getting the expected outcome. Could you please have a look i just updated my answer. The only problem is now wrong total. if I use [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All] instead of   [Dim Account].[Account Activity].CURRENTMEMBER, it's being got the same result

Comment: Please try to sort out this problem for me. i got stuck this wrong total

Comment: Please try to sort out this problem for me. i got stuck this wrong total

Comment: @Shamim I'm a little lost. Which of my three code samples is closest to what you require 1st, 2nd or 3rd? Let me delete the other two so I know which to work on.

Comment: i ran your 3 code and all 3 code executing same output like i said in my updated answer that if i use HAVING clause, it is compared with those who have different sign between Measures.Total and Measures.[Negative Total] and displayed that.Could you see my updated answer its almost done except Grand Total. Otherwise you can work out any of your 3 codes

Comment: @Shamim why is the following in your SELECT clause? `[Dim Account].[Account Activity].CURRENTMEMBER`

Comment: @Shamim apologies - but I do not understand your `ON ROWS` section - not mdx I am used to - can you please make it a little more like my on rows?

Comment: @Shamim Try playing with the values I've assigned to the SOLVE_ORDER values in your calculations - you might need to swap the 1 and 2

Comment: I just tried your code with SOLVE_ORDER but still didn't meet the expected outcome.

Comment: Let me explain more what i am trying to achieve. I have a Dimension of [Dim Account] which has the attributes like [Account Type],[Account Activity], [Account Marketing] etc. [Account Type] is  income, expense,..  [Account Activity] is like Advertising,Discounts, Sale of sponsorship,etc  [Account Marketing] is the combination of those things i mean advertising is the expense whereas discounts is stored as the negative income, so ultimately discounts will be treated as marketing expense.

Comment: That's why my 1st member is converting the income multiplied by -1 and i want to exclude those income are positive as they are income. I want to display the expenses and the converted negative income and finally add up those expense and converted negative income. In my MDX, the data are displayed perfectly but added up the original value  24010.44 -43380.4 +0 - 9181.32= -28,532.37 with +28,532.37. for Adding up the displayed value i used CURRENTMEMBER and VISUALTOTALS hoped that would add only positive value which was supposed to be 76572.